# Extract information from lists

Tags: r

I have a list of list that looks something like xyz in example below.

```
> x <- list(a=c("cat", "dog"), b=c("parrot", "chicken"), c=c("animal", "monkey"))
> y <- list(a=c("cat", "dog"), b=c("parrot", "chicken"), c=c("animal", "monkey"))
> z <- list(a=c("cat", "dog"), b=c("parrot", "chicken"), c=c("animal", "monkey"))
> xyz <- list(x, y, z)
> xyz
[[1]]
[[1]]$a
[1] "cat" "dog"

[[1]]$b
[1] "parrot"  "chicken"

[[1]]$c
[1] "animal" "monkey"


[[2]]
[[2]]$a
[1] "cat" "dog"

[[2]]$b
[1] "parrot"  "chicken"

[[2]]$c
[1] "animal" "monkey"


[[3]]
[[3]]$a
[1] "cat" "dog"

[[3]]$b
[1] "parrot"  "chicken"

[[3]]$c
[1] "animal" "monkey"
```

Now I want to extract information stored in $b for each list in xyz.

xyz will vary in length from time to time and so will also length of column b in xyz list. But it will always column b that I like to extract info from.

Desired output is a vector with information in column b for each list.

```
> desired_output <- data.frame(x=c(xyz[[1]]$b, xyz[[2]]$b, xyz[[3]]$b))
> desired_output
        x
1  parrot
2 chicken
3  parrot
4 chicken
5  parrot
6 chicken
```

My data looks more like.

```
> x <-list(df=data.frame((c(data.frame(a=c("cat", "dog"), b=c("cat", "dog"))))))
> x <-list(df=data.frame((c(data.frame(a=c("cat", "dog"), b=c("cat", "dog"))))))
> y <-list(df=data.frame((c(data.frame(a=c("cat", "dog"), b=c("cat", "dog"))))))
> z <-list(df=data.frame((c(data.frame(a=c("cat", "dog"), b=c("cat", "dog"))))))
> xyz<- list(x,y,z)
> class(xyz[[1]])
[1] "list"
> class(xyz[[1]]$df)
[1] "data.frame"
> xyz[[1]]$df$b
[1] cat dog
```

Now I would like to extract information in column b for each data frame in xyz.

Comment: Thanks for you quick comment. I see now that my list have slightly different structure.

unlist(lapply(xyz, "[[", "b$c"))

This wouldnt work?

Comment: do you have a data.frame named b somewhere with a column c?

Comment: yes.. Sorry for the duplicate and that doesnt solve my problem. I have a list of lists. Where each lists holds a data frame, and I would like to extract all information in column "b" of dataframe. 

I will write a better question, if I dont find an answer.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: All of the solutions posted so far worked with the example data you provided. If you need to make a new question for a new problem, then thats a new issue. Do a solid search over SO first, because chances are some one else has had the same problem before.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely a duplicate, but with some newer packages you can do this

```
library(purrr)
library(magrittr)
map(xyz, ~extract(.$b)) %>% unlist() %>% as.data.frame()
```

Comment: `xyz %>% map_df(~list(x=.$b))` might also be an option

Comment: ooo that's nice